# Changing Value from only one specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a group of generated inputs with the task of adding items to a shop list and adding the value to a sessionStorage Key:

[image]

```js
$('.increment').click(function increment() {
  $('.quantity-input').val(function(i, oldval) {
    return parseInt(oldval, 10) + 1;
  });
});


$('.drecement').click(function increment() {
  $('.quantity-input').val(function(i, oldval) {
    return parseInt(oldval, 10) - 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter-container">
  <input class="quantity-input" id=" 
       <?php echo $id_produtos; ?>" type="text" value="1">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button id="<?php echo $id_produtos; ?>" class="btn-arrow 
        increment">▲</button>
    <button id="<?php echo $id_produtos; ?>" class="btn-arrow 
        drecement">▼</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="counter-container">
  <input class="quantity-input" id=" 
       <?php echo $id_produtos; ?>" type="text" value="1">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button id="<?php echo $id_produtos; ?>" class="btn-arrow 
        increment">▲</button>
    <button id="<?php echo $id_produtos; ?>" class="btn-arrow 
        drecement">▼</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm changing also the others generated inputs:

[image]

How can I ONLY change the input that I'm clicking?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(this)` to refer to the related input by going up to the parent div using `.closest('.counter-container')` then select the desired input using `.find('.quantity-input')` like :

```
$(this).closest('.counter-container').find('.quantity-input').val(...
```

```js
$('.increment').click(function increment() {
  $(this).closest('.counter-container').find('.quantity-input').val(function(i, oldval) {
    return parseInt(oldval, 10) + 1;
  });
});


$('.drecement').click(function increment() {
  $(this).closest('.counter-container').find('.quantity-input').val(function(i, oldval) {
    return parseInt(oldval, 10) - 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter-container">
  <input class="quantity-input" id="x_1" type="text" value="1">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button id="1" class="btn-arrow increment">▲</button>
    <button id="1" class="btn-arrow drecement">▼</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="counter-container">
  <input class="quantity-input" id="x_2" type="text" value="1">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button id="y_2" class="btn-arrow increment">▲</button>
    <button id="z_2" class="btn-arrow drecement">▼</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="counter-container">
  <input class="quantity-input" id="x_3" type="text" value="1">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button id="y_3" class="btn-arrow increment">▲</button>
    <button id="z_3" class="btn-arrow drecement">▼</button>
  </div>
</div>
```